# Sharepoint 2013 Adduser and groups using REST API

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-rest-api

I've a requirement to create user in a SharePoint using the **REST API and c#**. How to achieve this?

Most of the article show using REST API in jquery and JavaScript but I've a requirement to do this using c#. And also I checked in MSDN for the same but they have given the JavaScript code where `<host web url>` is given where do I get the host web url. I'm using SharePoint 2013 which I'm accessing remotely. I don't have server side access so I need to do it through Rest API.

Please suggest some idea.

Comment: have you tried this one: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/d2ee01/rest-calls-to-sharepoint-2013-through-console-application/

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected void btnItemCreation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 { 
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
    {
       using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
       {
          SPListItem item;
          SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList("List_Name");
          item = list.Items.Add();
          item["People_or_Group_Name"] = GetpeopleProjectManagerValues();
          item.Update();
       }
   }
}
protected SPFieldUserValueCollection GetpeopleProjectManagerValues()
        {
            try
            {
                string[] userarray = PeoplePickerID.CommaSeparatedAccounts.ToString().Split(',');
                SPFieldUserValueCollection usercollection = new SPFieldUserValueCollection();
                for (int i = 0; i < userarray.Length; i++)
                {
                    SPFieldUserValue usertoadd = ConvertLoginAccount(userarray[i]);
                    usercollection.Add(usertoadd);
                }

                return usercollection;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
public SPFieldUserValue ConvertSaveLoginAccount(string userid)
        {
            SPFieldUserValue uservalue = null;
            try
            {
                using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url))
                {
                    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                    {
                        SPUser requireduser = web.EnsureUser(userid);
                        uservalue = new SPFieldUserValue(web, requireduser.ID, requireduser.Name);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                }
            return uservalue;
        }
```

Comment: Try this above code to add any SharePoint user to Insert data using People Picker

Comment: The question was about using C# and the **REST API**. Your code gives an example of C# and server side code.